# Mapping Java List<> to protobuf repeated string

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am working on a task where I need to call a `service B` which takes an argument `@RequestBody` as a protobuf object from `service A`

`service A` has a normal POJO which contains few fields and a `List<>`. I am populating the list and sending it over the http call.

`service B` receives the object and does the mapping from normal POJO to protobuf.
There is validation which checks if list is empty or not. And somehow the list size is coming as 0 (by calling the protobuf generated code to get the count) and validation is failing.

I am assuming that it has to do something while the POJO is getting mapped to the protobuf object.

Any help to resolve the issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear: It's service A which creates the protobuf from the POJOs and passes it down the line, right? Then you should be able to look only at `A` to find out how it might be creating an empty list. If you are passing the POJO over the service using some other serialization mechanism... why use protobuf at all?

Comment: No. From service A I am sending a normal pojo in the request to service B. It's service B that expects the protobuf object.
Though I was able to solve the issue. It seems protobuf `repeated` variable must end with `List` keyword in POJO explicitly for the automatic pojo to protobuf object conversion. I just attached `List` to the variable name and it started working.

Comment: It would be good to mention what the "pojo to protobuf conversion" mechanism is, and at which point it's applied. That's certainly not a standard protobuf feature.

Comment: So there is no "mechanism" as such. Both `service A` and `service B` are simple springboot project where service A sends an `http request` to service B. The request object shared sent by service A is a simple POJO. But the method in the controller of service B, which gets the request takes an argument of `protobuf` type. So I am basically not doing anything myself here. It would be great if you can explain how it works with `List` and not without it :)

Comment: From what you said, it looks like there's some Spring mechanism that does this translation; I don't know anything about Spring but that definitely isn't a part of protobuf. I would say that this is much more a springboot question than a protobuf one.

Comment: Ah might be that spring is doing some magic behind the scenes (like it always does). Thanks for clarifying that it has nothing to do with protobuf at least.